# Get the inserted records in last query/Get changed rows count (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert, database-migration

I'm currently migrating an old DB structure to a new one. I'm creating an SQL script (because I might need to preform this operation more than once) and I got stuck on a certain operation I wish to do.

So the relevant tables/fields for this script:

> **states** -> old table, where I'm gonna get the records for labels

- id
- default_name
- color_code
- state

---

> **freelancers** -> old table

- idfreelancer
- (freelancer info, a lot of unimportant fields)
- idstate

---

> **labels**  -> new table, to store labels (freelancers can have several labels, labels can have several freelancers)

- idlabel
- name
- color_code
- idcreator

---

> **free_labels** -> new table, to cross reference labels and freelancers

- idlabel
- idfreelancer

---

So, what I want:

1. Copy every record from states where `default_name IS NULL` to labels.
2. Delete every record from states where `default_name IS NULL`
3. If a freelancer had a state that had default_name NULL, then he should be changed to idstate=1 and insert the corresponding label in the free_labels table.

---

For the first 2 points I've come up with the query:

```
INSERT INTO labels(name,color_code,idcreator)
SELECT state AS name,color_code,2 AS idcreator FROM states
where default_name IS NULL;

DELETE FROM states WHERE default_name IS NULL;
```

I've forced the idcreator to 2, and that's intended, I know it might seem strange.

---

For the third point I was think of using something like:

```
INSERT INTO free_labels(idlabel,idfreelancer)
VALUES
((SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM labels),
(SELECT f.idfreelancer FROM freelancers f, states s,
WHERE f.idstate=s.id AND s.default_name IS NULL))
```

**Note:** I haven't tried this query yet, so I don't even know if I even can do an `INSERT INTO` with a double `SELECT`.

And use this query before deleting the records from states.
However this query has 2 problems for me.

- It doesn't change the state of the freelancer,
- And, most importantly, it "breaks" for multiple records, since `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will only get me the last inserted record.

---

I'm a bit lost on how to do this operation, I think this could be done by getting the amount of changed records from a query, but I don't know if that's possible through SQL (I can also use PHP if needed, though, I'd rather not).

Another thing I've considered is that maybe I could do an `INSERT` with a `JOIN`, so I would insert the records in `labels` and `free_labels` at the same time. But again, I don't know if this is possible with SQL and if it even would solve my problem.

I would really like to avoid migrating this records manually...

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could insert into labels and add the old id column. Then insert into freelancers and add the old idstate column. Map new id of freelancers and labels based on the old ids. Finally delete all the old tables and the 2 old columns in the new tables

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I actually had thought about something like that. I just didn't want to screw the AUTO_INCREMENT in the labels table. You're saying to map the new id's based on the old ones, but I'm not really seeing how i'm suposed to do that. Could you provide an answer as an example?

Comment: Just to be sure : You'll keep the `states` table with `default_name` `NOT NULL`, you'll move the `NULL` ones to the `labels` table. The `freelancers`table will remain the same except for the rows where `idstate` is linked to a `default_name` `NULL`, you'll set `idstate` to 1. You want the `free_labels` table to be filled with `idlabel` from `labels` and its corresponding `idfreelancer` from `freelancers`. That way you'll have 4 tables instead of 2 : `states` with `NOT NULL` `default_name`, `labels`, `freelancers` and `free_labels`

Comment: Yes! Exacly that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all you create your new labels table with one more column :

```
CREATE TABLE labels (
  idlabel int PRIMARY KEY AUTO-INCREMENT,
  #Some other columns....
  old_id int
  );
```

Then you insert your data into this table like you did plus the old_id (and remove the rows) :

```
INSERT INTO labels(name,color_code,idcreator,old_id)
  SELECT state AS name,color_code,2 AS idcreator, id AS old_id FROM states
  where default_name IS NULL;

DELETE FROM states WHERE default_name IS NULL;
```

You can now map your freelancer id with the old stateid in the free_labels table :

```
INSERT INTO free_labels (idlabels, idfreelancers)
  SELECT labels.idlabel, freelancers.idfreelancer 
  FROM labels 
  JOIN freelancers
  ON labels.old_id = freelancers.idstate;
```

All you need to do now is set the idstate of freelancers to 1 (take care not having a state with id=1 by the way or one said to check free_labels, else put it to NULL or 0), remove the column in labels and that's it :

```
UPDATE freelancers SET idstate = 1 WHERE idfreelancer IN (SELECT idfreelancer FROM free_labels);

ALTER TABLE labels DROP COLUMN old_id;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really like this solution! The state 1 will never have default_name NULL so its fine!